# Basic SQL Insert statement approach

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given that I have two tables

- Customer (id int, username varchar)
- Order (customer_id int, order_date datetime)

Now I want to insert into Order table based on customer information which is available in Customer table.

There are a couple of ways I can approch this problem.

First - I can query the customer information into a variable and then use it in an INSERT statement.

```
DECLARE @Customer_ID int
SELECT @Customer_ID = id FROM Customer where username = 'john.smith'
INSERT INTO Orders (customer_id, order_date) VALUES (@Customer_ID, GETDATE())
```

Second Approach is to use a combination of INSERT and SELECT query.

```
INSERT INTO Orders (customer_id, order_date)
SELECT id, GETDATE() FROM Customers
WHERE username = 'john.smith'
```

So my question is that which is a better way to proceed in terms of speed and overhead and why ? I know if we have a lot of information getting queried from Customer table then the second approach is much better.

p.s. I was asked this question in one of the technical interviews.

Comment: How did you answer the question inthe interview?

Comment: I gave them a similar answer as you did. Just wanted to get everybodys opinion on it. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second approach is better.

The first approach will fail if the customer is not found. No check is being done to make sure the customer id has been returned.

The second approach will do nothing if the customer is not found.

From an overhead approach why create variables if they are not needed. Set based sql is usually the better approach.

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend either approach. Why do you have the customer name and not the id in the first place? Don't you have a user interface that maintains a reference to the current customer by holding the ID in its state? Doing the lookup by name exposes you to potentially selecting the wrong customer.

If you must do this for reasons unknown to me, the 2nd approach is certainly more efficient because it only contains one statement.

Answer (score 1):

In a typical real-world order-entry system, the user has already looked the Customer up via a Search interface, or has chosen the customer from a list of customers displayed alphabetically; so your client program, when it goes to insert an order for that customer, already knows the CustomerID.

Furthermore, the order date is typically defaulted to getdate() as part of the ORDERS table definition, and your query can usually ignore that column.

But to handle multiple line items on an order, your insert into ORDER_HEADER needs to return the order header id so that it can be inserted into the ORDER DETAIL line item(s) child rows.

Answer (score 0):

Make the customer id in order table a foreign key which refers to customer table.